# Any A/B switch to use a Dell docking station in two computers? Or any other solution?

Tags: usb, switch, splitters

I have a Dell D6000 docking station that provide me access to all my devices, including power to my laptop, I want to have the ability to switch the docking station to a second laptop without the need to unplug and plug-in the USB-C cable.

I'm unable to find an A/B USB switch type C.
Any recommendation?

[image]

Comment: This would be called a [USB-C KVM Switch](https://www.iogear.com/product/GUD3C04/). The A/B switch and docking station would be all-in-one. (I realized that the linked product doesn't support dual monitors, but it should set you on the right path.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer for you, but may have a useful alternative.

I have worked with many computers of various flavors and long ago gave up the idea of switches for the various displays and keyboards and whatnot. Just too much of a pain. Instead I use exported displays (X windows for unix/linux, RDP for Windows). That way I can sit at exactly one monitor and see any or all of the machines with one keyboard and pointer. To avoid confusion I tend to put each machine on a different desktop, but that's just my preference. Using exactly one set of HID's makes the "feel" of each computer the same. An added advantage is that it is possible to cut-and-paste between computers, something I use more than I expected to.

Comment: That is not a bad idea... not sure if would work in my case since my objective is to have all my displays available for the connected laptop.

Comment: Think of your network and the remote display capability as the software equivalent to your AB switch. Even better since it becomes "A and/or B" on your displays. That is, leave your primary machine connected and export the second laptop to it and you're all done. That is, unless you want to turn off the first laptop when using the second one.